# Add URL image to button click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, url, uibutton

I searched some tutorial for add UIImage to button for click event. How to add URL path

image to button..For example code:

```
UIButton *imageView=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((320*index)+countFlag*80+ 2, 5, 75, 75)];
                imageView.tag=i+1;
                [imageView addTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
                [imageView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
                [imageView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];
                switch ((i+1)%5) {
                    case 0:
                        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];               

                        break;

                    case 1:
                        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                        break;
    }
```

Comment: you want to show button with background image?

Comment: Use EGOButton for the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this for ur button(imageView)

```
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"imageurl"]]]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: which ios version r us using?, u r setting image for imageview or uibutton?

Comment: Using ios 6.1, Set image to uibutton.                        UIButton *imageView=[[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake((320*index)+countFlag*80+ 2, 5, 75, 75)];
        imageView.tag=i+1;
        [imageView addTarget:self action:@selector(imageViewClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [imageView.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor];
        [imageView.layer setBorderWidth:1.0f];

Comment: It's working. Thanks..Then is it possible to load multiple url to uibutton?

Answer (score 3):

Its better to use this `UIButton+WebCache.h` category of [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) It supports the asynchronous loading of image for your button. You can use any of the following methods.

```
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState:(UIControlState)state;
- (void)setImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState:(UIControlState)state placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder;
```

It also provides background image asynchronous loading for `UIButton`

```
- (void)setBackgroundImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState:(UIControlState)state;
- (void)setBackgroundImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url forState:(UIControlState)state placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholder;
```

Don't forget to include `SDWebImage` to your project and `UIButton+WebCache.h` file into your implementation file.

Reference: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Answer (score 2):

For Normal state,

```
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

and for Clicked (Selected) state,

```
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];
[imageView setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
    EGOImageButton* btnUserImage = [[EGOImageButton alloc] initWithPlaceholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ProfilePictureDefault.png"]];
    btnUserImage.frame = CGRectMake(10,5,25,25);
    btnUserImage.highlighted = NO;
    [self addSubview:btnUserImage];

    btnUserImage.imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:Url];
```